# How to optimize Bulk upload users Azure B2C JAVA?

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Hi I need to migrate 20k users I have followed the Microsoft documentation for the SDK and saw some of the post on stack overflow but I still don't see how I can bulk upload my users to Azure AD B2C. The below method will take me 4 hours.

```
GraphServiceClient<Request> graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( tokenCredentialAuthProvider ).buildClient();

for (DBuser dbuser : users) {
com.microsoft.graph.models.User user = new com.microsoft.graph.models.User();
            user.accountEnabled = true;
            user.displayName = dbuser.getFirstName();

            final LinkedList<ObjectIdentity> identitiesList = new LinkedList<ObjectIdentity>();
            ObjectIdentity identities = new ObjectIdentity();

            identities.signInType = "emailAddress";
            identities.issuerAssignedId = dbuser.getEmail();
            identities.issuer = "issuer";
            identitiesList.add(identities);

            user.identities = identitiesList;

            PasswordProfile passwordProfile = new PasswordProfile();
            passwordProfile.password = dbuser.getPassword();
            passwordProfile.forceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false;

            user.passwordProfile = passwordProfile;
            user.passwordPolicies = "DisablePasswordExpiration";

        graphClient.users().buildRequest().post(user);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell script to create local accounts in bulk

```html
Connect-azuread
$users = import-csv C:\temp\Admin.csv
$PasswordProfile = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PasswordProfile
$PasswordProfile.Password = "P@$$w0rd"
foreach ($usr in $users)
{
New-AzureADUser -DisplayName $usr.name -PasswordProfile $PasswordProfile UserPrincipalName $usr.upn -AccountEnabled $true -MailNickName $usr.email
}
```

Below is how my C:\temp\test.csv file looks:

[image]

Reference : Use Graph Call for Social Accounts :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-create-a-user-with-social-and-local-account-identities

Creating bulk social identities via Graph API, you can combine multiple requests in one HTTP call using JSON batching as documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching

Note: You may need to modify it as per your requirement

Comment: "Creating bulk social identities via Graph API," What is different then what I did above? How do I create it in bulk?